# GCE Alert Policies for Instance( n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Can anyone please help me to define the standard threshold value for disk read operations alert (IO) and disk write operations alert in the GCP VM instance, We have upgraded the VM instance from n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory) to n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory) and the threshold was 100/s for disk read operations?

Standard SSD attached to VM of 40GB.

Comment: What a standard threshold? What do you want to have? where are you stuck? What did you try?

Comment: Were did you get this 100/s operations value from ?